# pycryptodome setup.py causing an error when installing pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, pycrypto, pycryptodome, pyrebase

I am trying to install Pyrebase, but I keep getting an error that I believe is caused by setup.py for pycryptodome. I have searched all over but cannot find a solution, does anyone know how to solve this?

My output is below - I added in (...) in places to truncate the output, which was creating and copying libraries.

Thanks for the help

```
(backend-ragxWAh7) bash-3.2$ pip install Pyrebase
Collecting Pyrebase
 (...)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycryptodome
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycryptodome ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/rafilurie/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-ragxWAh7/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/d5/zwblxz7d3gxcks_wgjcyxw_00000gn/T/pip-install-q_NyfS/pycryptodome/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/d5/zwblxz7d3gxcks_wgjcyxw_00000gn/T/pip-wheel-8ox7HU --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto
  copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto
  (...)
  copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS/SigVerPSS_186-3.rsp -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
  warning: PCTBuildPy: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  running build_ext
  warning: no support for Intel AESNI instructions
  building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src
  cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DLTC_NO_ASM -Isrc/ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src/MD2.o
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pycryptodome
  Running setup.py clean for pycryptodome
Failed to build pycryptodome
Installing collected packages: pycryptodome, Pyrebase
  Running setup.py install for pycryptodome ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/rafilurie/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-ragxWAh7/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/d5/zwblxz7d3gxcks_wgjcyxw_00000gn/T/pip-install-q_NyfS/pycryptodome/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/d5/zwblxz7d3gxcks_wgjcyxw_00000gn/T/pip-record-1TJZWz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/rafilurie/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-ragxWAh7/include/site/python2.7/pycryptodome:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    (...)
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5/SigVer15_186-3.rsp -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5/SigGen15_186-3.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5/SigGen15_186-2.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS/SigGenPSS_186-2.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS/SigGenPSS_186-3.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS/SigVerPSS_186-3.rsp -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
    warning: PCTBuildPy: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    warning: no support for Intel AESNI instructions
    building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DLTC_NO_ASM -Isrc/ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src/MD2.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/rafilurie/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-ragxWAh7/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/d5/zwblxz7d3gxcks_wgjcyxw_00000gn/T/pip-install-q_NyfS/pycryptodome/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/d5/zwblxz7d3gxcks_wgjcyxw_00000gn/T/pip-record-1TJZWz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/rafilurie/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-ragxWAh7/include/site/python2.7/pycryptodome" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/d5/zwblxz7d3gxcks_wgjcyxw_00000gn/T/pip-install-q_NyfS/pycryptodome/
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a valid C compiler environment (`xcode`).
See also here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path.

Answer (score 0):

install `pycryptodome` from github

go into `lib/Crypto/PublicKey`

get `RSA.py` file from there

and import it into `pyerbase.py` file as single file like `import rsa`